# If something happened again, did it recur or reoccur?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, synonyms

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcThN1dZMe4) (from 8 min.53 sec.) shows that the verb recur is often pronounced as reoccur, and the host of the show explains this as a case of a mispronunciation: there's no such word as "reoccur" and what may be pronounced as "reoccur" should be pronounced as "recur".

It  seems that either the speakers don't see any difference between the two verbs, or this difference is far too small to be taken into account.

At the same time, the entries for both [*reoccur*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reoccur) and [*recur*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recur), and for the relating nouns *recurrence* and *reoccurrence* (the same links) can be found  in some of the dictionaries; the WordWebPro off-line dictionary is among them.

The question is this:

If there is a fine difference in the use of the verbs *recur* and *reoccur* and of the nouns *recurrence* and *reoccurrence*, what is it?

Comment: The guy on the left is just flat out wrong when he says "reoccured is not a word." This has to call into question the rest of the information (or is it misinformation) given in the video. Your best bet regarding pronunciation is a good dictionary, coupled with forvo.com for variations.

Comment: @AlanCarmack - Thanks, Alan, for one more useful link provided by you; it's been bookmarked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are separate words.

Something **reoccurs** if it happens more than once.

Something **recurs** if it happens more than once and at a regular interval. A good example would be your electricity bill – most people pay monthly or every quarter, and so they have a *monthly-recurring* or *quarterly-recurring* bill.

---

Compare these dictionary definitions (from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/)):

> [**reoccur**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reoccur)
>   [NO OBJECT]
>   Occur again or repeatedly:
>   "*ulcers tend to reoccur after treatment has stopped*"
>
> [**recur**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recur)
>   [NO OBJECT]
>   Occur again periodically or repeatedly:
>   "*when the symptoms recurred, the doctor diagnosed something different*"
>   (as adjective **recurring**) "*a recurring theme*"

As you can see from the definitions, there is some overlap. In general conversation I would not be surprised to hear *recur* and *reoccur* used interchangeably. In formal or professional correspondence (like a bill), however, I would expect the words to be used as described in the first part of my answer.

Comment: +1 I suggest mentioning which dictionary you cite,  since you are quoting from it. Also, it's nice to know which dictionary you're referring to without having to click on the link(s).

Comment: @AlanCarmack: Thanks for the suggestion, I've added a note about it.

Comment: Also, a recurring dream/nightmare, drinking bout, feature, motif, problem etc. A really good answer; thanks a lot.